# Android send file more then 1 MB via Intent to mail application

Tags: android, performance, email, android-intent, android-activity

I'm getting "Failed Binder Transaction Error" when I want to grab the text from  TextView and put it like text in Intent 
For small text it works, I'm getting text correctly and after I have it in my mail application.

Is there any way to put text whatever size it has from my TextView into Mail application?
When and how would you keep track of the files and make sure they I'm deleted and not spamming the device. What is the  design that solution?

The code I have and which works with small amount of text is below..

```
private void sendLogMail() {
        try {
            if ("".equals(logTextView.getText().toString().trim())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no log information to send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                String[] mailReceiver = new String[] { getString(R.string.logviewer_mailto)};
                startActivity( Intent.createChooser(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setData(Uri.parse("mail:to")).setType("text/plain")
                                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailReceiver)
                                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Log:  " + Utils.formatReadableTimestamp( System.currentTimeMillis()))
                                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getInfo() + "\n" + "\n" + "Log: "+ "\n"+logTextView.getText()),
                                 "Please config your  mail account") );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            getLog().error("Error sending logfile as email", e);
        }
    }

    private String getInfo() throws Exception {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("Terminal ID: " + getCore().getID())
                .append("\n")
                .append("License ID: " + getCore().getLicense())
                .append("\n")
                .append("Outlet ID: " + getCore().getOtherID())
                .append("\n")
                .append("Name: "+" "+getLoggedIn().getFormattedName())
                .append("/")
                .append(" ")
                .append(getLoggedIn().getId())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to put text whatever size it has from my TextView into Mail application?

Options include:

- Writing it to a file on internal storage and using `FileProvider` to serve it to the mail client, putting the `Uri` in `EXTRA_STREAM`
- Creating some `ContentProvider` to serve it from RAM to the mail client, putting the `Uri` in `EXTRA_STREAM`
- Writing it to a file on external storage to serve it to the mail client, putting the `Uri` to the file in `EXTRA_STREAM`

> When and how would you keep track of the files and make sure they I'm deleted and not spamming the device.

I would keep the file on internal storage, perhaps in `getCacheDir()`, then delete it after 24 hours or some such.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yesterday I implemented the solution. The code below, in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to implement the solution
In final opens standard Android ICS preinstalled mail application with attached file to the mail.

Hope this would help somebody also

The code is below

The general method

```
 private void sendLogMail() {
            try {
                if ("".equals(logTextView.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no log information to send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    String[] mailReceiver = new String[] { getString(R.string.logviewer_mailto)};
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    StringBuilder logBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                    logBuffer.append( getTerminalInfo() ).append( "\n\n" );
                    logBuffer.append( "Log attached!" );

                    File logFile = writeLogFile( getInfo() );
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( logFile );

                    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mail:to"));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailReceiver);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Log:  " + Utils.formatReadableTime( System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, logBuffer.toString() );

                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    if (uri != null) {
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    }

                    startActivity( Intent.createChooser( emailIntent, "Please choose the mail client to use" ) );

                }
            }
```

Here I simply write it to file

```
private File writeLogFile( String terminalInfo ) throws IOException {
        File dir = Logger.getInstance().getPublicLogDirectory();

        File logFile = new File( dir.getAbsolutePath(),+Utils.getFormattedTime( System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".log" );
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( logFile ) );

        try {
            os.write( terminalInfo.getBytes() );
            os.write( "\n\n".getBytes() );
            os.write( logTextView.getText().toString().getBytes() );
            os.flush();
        }
        finally {
            os.close();
        }

        return logFile;
    }

private String getInfo() throws Exception {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("Terminal ID: " + getCore().getID())
                .append("\n")
                .append("License ID: " + getCore().getLicense())
                .append("\n")
                .append("Outlet ID: " + getCore().getOtherID())
                .append("\n")
                .append("Name: "+" "+getLoggedIn().getFormattedName())
                .append("/")
                .append(" ")
                .append(getLoggedIn().getId())
                .toString();
    }

Make directory



     public File getPublicLogDirectory() {
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                dir.mkdirs();

                File logDir = new File( dir, "logs" );
                logDir.mkdirs();

                return logDir;
            }

    check if files exist
        public void cleanPublicLogDirectory() throws IOException {
            File dir = getPublicLogDirectory();

            File logFiles[] = dir.listFiles();

            if( logFiles != null && logFiles.length > 0 ) {
                for( File logFile : logFiles ) {
                    if( logFile.getName().endsWith( ".log" ) ) {
                        long lastModified = logFile.lastModified();

                        // Delete files older than 24 hours
                        if( (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastModified) > 1 ) { // 1000*60*60*24 ) { 
                            logFile.delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```